# Excel Data_validation is not working with string in variable

Tags: python, excel, api, validation

any help is appreciated

```
for issue in d:

    str1 = str1+"," + issue['name']
    str1= "\'\""+str1[1:] +"\"\'"
print(str1)                    **#not working for this str1**

#str1='" Automation, Management"'   **# work for this str1**

dv= DataValidation(type='list',formula1=str1)

worksheet.add_data_validation(dv)

dv.add(worksheet['B2'])
```

type of both str is string only

Answer (score 0):

str1= """+str1[1:] +"""

worked after removing '